# How to automate input type="color" in selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, css, html, selenium

[image]

Scenario: 
Choose color, enter other details and save.
when I click on the html element color (input type=color) it opens a color picker which is a window pop_up.

```
<input type="color" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" style="width: 70%;" ng-model="modalData[0].StrokeColor" placeholder="color" aria-invalid="false">
```

this is the html element for me.

The default value is null for the element. Without picking the color i cant save this form.
i tried using js command to set the value for the element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse')[0].setAttribute('value', '#32CD32')
```

this changes the value fo the color but has no impact on either the UI or the save.

how can i handle this, i am not good with scite script. any help.
Thanks.

Comment: To automate windows popup, you can try with auto it or any other automation tool which supports windows UI.

Comment: is there no other way to automate input color? if no then please help me with autoIT script.

Comment: Once you are able to `changes the value for the color` why not to try clicking on `Save` button?

Comment: when i change the value for the element using javaScript, and when i look for the element again it has the 'value' attribute added in the HTML code but when is try saving the for it asks me to pic color.
so the change is actually not affecting any thing.
I think it has something to do with ng-model="modalData[0].StrokeColor", its a function that picks the color, and not reading the value attribute at all. trying to get the code for this function.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) w;
WebElement ColorElement =w.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='color']"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '#FF0000')",ColorElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

For me simply calling `.sendKeys('#FF0000')` on the web element worked with Selenium 4 + Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in python. In addition to choosing a color, I needed to perform a simulated user action in the palette. `ActionChains` helped me.

```
action = ActionChains(self.driver)
element = self.find_element(locator)
element.click()

for i in range(3):
  action.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
  for n in range(3):
    action.send_keys(5)
    action.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
  action.perform()

[palette in my chrome][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWS4V.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYVmc.png
```