# How to automate input type=“color” [ html5 color picker ] in selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, automation

Scenario: Choose color, and Close the window. when I click on the html element color (input type=color) it opens a color picker which is a window pop_up. I am not able to view DOM of the window.
I want to either click on any color and close window or enter any hex code in the textbox present on window popup. Please help me with the code for the same

[image]

Please note - tried with this solution [How to automate input type="color" in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386482/how-to-automate-input-type-color-in-selenium-webdriver)
but it is not working for me on html5.

Comment: _but it is not working for me on html5._ are you facing any exception or it just do nothing ?

Comment: It does nothing,

Comment: Maybe use JavaScript to set the value, and trigger an `onchange` event on the `<input>` element using JavaScript? Can you describe more what you mean by "it does nothing?" Visibly, nothing is happening on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the value of the input color box after the user selects a color and clicks on the close button / enters the hex value. Use the following for getting the value of the Input color Box :

```
<body>

<input type="color" onchange="changeFunction(this)">

<script>

function changeFunction(element)
{
  console.log(element.value)
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: If you need any other info wrt the input type color, Pl ask. What exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to select any color from the color picker popup window and close the window.

Comment: That is the default behaviour. You select the color and then manually close the window. It is Working for me. Did you mean this -- Once you select the color from the color picker popup the window should be automatically closed ?

Comment: I meant -  select the color and then manually close the window.
Please suggest where exactly to use this code
<body>

<input type="color" onchange="changeFunction(this)">

<script>

function changeFunction(element)
{
  console.log(element.value)
}

</script>
</body>

Basically I want to write automation script [ using selenium]

Comment: Once you select the color and then manually close the window, the changeFunction will be called. You will get the value of the chosen color. Do whatever you want with it...

Comment: I do not have access to UI, it pre built UI on which I am trying to write automation tests.